# Making an array of random integers that add up to a certain number

Tags: arrays, algorithm, integer

I want to make an array of 7 integers, each of which is a random value between 2 and 5. That's easy, but I want to make it so the total sum of these integers must be 20. Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend writing some code. :)  After you write some code and it doesn't do what you expect, then I would post a question.  Otherwise, this type of question is more of a "code golf" question, not a programming problem.

Comment: To reach you goal, you can't have evenly distributed integers. Any constraints on the expected distribution?

Comment: No, that's fine. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate 6 random numbers.

Calculate the sum of these numbers.

if the sum is larger than 19 or smaller than 15: start over.

7th number is 20 - sum

Comment: Improvements: start over as soon as you see that you will go beyond 20 if you add `2 * numbers remaining`. Or change the last number instead of starting over again.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger it is tricky to modify the partial set (e.g. recalc a single number under certain conditions) because it is all too easy to destroy perfect randomness. Your suggestion tends to make the last number smaller than the rest for example.

Comment: Be aware that this does NOT give you uniform distribution of the numbers, in fact, I believe the last number is distributed normally (for larger data sets).

Comment: @amit I agree, the last number is *not* evenly distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an array of seven twos. You now have a sum of 14. Add one to a random slot in the array six times, taking care to not overflow a value to more than five:

```
arr = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}
n = 6

while n > 0:
    m = random(7)
    if arr[m] < 5:
        arr[m]++
        n--
```

Comment: I think this will make a 5 less likely than a 4 and so on

Comment: Yes, probably, but isn't the expected value for each element 20/7, so somewhat short of 3 anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Brute force: keep recalculating until you get an answer

```
import random

def random_sums_to(lower, top, n, sums_to):
    a = [random.randint(lower, top) for _ in range(n)]
    if sum(a) != sums_to:
        return random_sums_to(lower, top, n, sums_to)
    return a

print random_sums_to(2, 5, 7, 20)
```

Comment: There is a risk that this runs quite long

Comment: That is indeed always the risk with brute force solutions, but for the values given in the question it returns an answer within milliseconds.

Comment: It is more risk with the combination of  _random_ and _brute force_

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make sure to get the *exact same* distribution at each position proceed as follows:

1. Calculate a list with all possible sequences
2. Pick one of these sequences randomly